# Как узнать мак адрес удаленного узла в интернете?

Tags: linux, windows, сеть, mac-address

Когда я писал программу для локальной сети, то чтобы узнать мак адрес, я отсылал запрос вроде бы на адрес 255.255.255.255 с вопросом кто такой то адрес. Но заходя на какой нибудь сайт в интернете я через wireshark не вижу чтобы передавался мак адрес. Видно только запрос и ответ dns сервера. Но откуда тогда компьютер знает на какой мак отсылать данные?

Comment: В общем случае никак. Для нелокальных адресов запросы отправляются на ваш gateway (скорее всего это ваш роутер)

Comment: Первое попавшееся описание как работает сеть http://ciscotips.ru/ip-and-mac

Comment: всё понятно, спасибо, я об этом тоже немного думал, но не долго.

Comment: `~# nmap hostname` можно так

Comment: значит, чтобы отправить пакет собранный вручную, можно будет отправлять на нужный хост с маком шлюза.

Answer (score 1):

> Как узнать мак адрес удаленного узла в интернете?

точно так же, как и в локальной сети (это ирония) — спросить при помощи протокола [*arp*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARP). цитата из статьи:

> Перед тем как передать пакет сетевого уровня через сегмент Ethernet, сетевой стек проверяет кэш ARP, чтобы выяснить, не зарегистрирована ли в нём уже нужная информация об узле-получателе. Если такой записи в кэше ARP нет, то выполняется широковещательный запрос ARP. Этот запрос для устройств в сети имеет следующий смысл: «Кто-нибудь знает физический адрес устройства, обладающего следующим IP-адресом?» Когда получатель с этим IP-адресом примет этот пакет, то должен будет ответить: «Да, это мой IP-адрес. Мой физический адрес следующий: …» После этого отправитель обновит свой кэш ARP и будет способен передать информацию получателю.

одна только проблема: такие запросы и ответы не смогут покинуть вашу локальную сеть.

---

> Но откуда тогда компьютер знает на какой мак отсылать данные?

посмотрит в [*таблице маршрутизации*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0_%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%88%D1%80%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8): какому шлюзу отправлять пакет, сделает arp-запрос (если mac-адреса этого шлюза ещё нет в arp-кэше), и отправит.

Comment: Посмотрите, что такое IPv6.